# How to handle multiple errors thrown by an utility function?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, user-experience, coding-style

I have a function `examples(a,b,c,…)`. Each argument can throw an error. All of them are handled the same way. I guess `examples([array])` would fall in the same category.

In my code I have something like that currently:

```
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    try { this.example(arg[i]) }
    catch (e) { log(e) }
  }
```

From an user perspective Id like to be able to see the errors of all arguments at once instead of fixing one and then discovering the next one etc. But I end up catching myself which seems, to me, not desirable for an utility function.

Is there a way to rethrow *all* errors at once?

**What are the best practices?**

If there's a standard, why is it being recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can `throw` pretty much anything, but rather than just a simple *Array*, you may find you have more maneuverability using a custom error type

```
function ErrorCollection(msg) {
    this.name = 'ErrorCollection';
    this.message = msg || '';
    this.errors = [];
}
ErrorCollection.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ErrorCollection.prototype.constructor = ErrorCollection;
ErrorCollection.prototype.push = function (e) {
    return this.errors.push(e);
}

// ...

var i, ec = new ErrorCollection();
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    try {
        throw new Error('Error ' + i);
    } catch (e) {
        ec.push(e);
    }
}
// do something with ec, e.g.
if (ec.errors.length) {
    console.log(ec, ec.errors);
    throw ec;
}
```

---

An example of stopping on the first error then validity checking the remainder

```
var i, a = [];
for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    try { // assume everything will work
        this.example(arguments[i]);
    } catch (e) { // our assumption was wrong
        a.push({arg: i, val: arguments[i]});
        for (++i; i < arguments.length; ++i) { // loop from where we left off
            if (!this.valid_arg(arguments[i])) { // some costly test
                a.push({arg: i, val: arguments[i]});
            }
        }
        throw a; // throw the list of bad args up a level
    }
}
```

If the validity test will be fast/isn't costly then you may consider doing it in advance of your main loop instead of waiting for the first error, as you should then be able to avoid `try..catch` at this level entirely.

Comment: That's a sound approach but seems quite useless if I only have one error.

Comment: @Knu So if your `for` loop if `len` is `1`, but the reason we do it is for the abstract case, not a specific one

Comment: How to throw isn't the only thing I am asking about. I need to know whether it is expected to treat other arguments even if the first one has thrown an error. Would the user want that? I would.

Comment: @Knu I guess this depends on what `this.example` does and whether there are other ways to verify args, i.e. you need to ask yourself "does my code need to be immediately halted to prevent unexpected results?" If the answer is no, let them pile up then throw them. If the answer is yes, either stop on the first or consider if there is an easy way to verify the rest of your args without invoking `this.example`

Comment: This is a matter of taste that's why I was asking about conventions. It has more to do with UX than code.